# Accessing current element on backbone.js-events?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, element

I know that I can use jQuery to access the view's element in `backbone.js` by `$(this.el)`, but what about accessing elements that are handled by backbone's event binding?

How can I target the clicked div with id `#button` directly from my event handler, as shown below? Do i really need to create a subview for this?

```
Backbone.View.extend({

    el : "#container",

    events: {
        'click #button' : 'buttonHandler'
    },

    buttonHandler: function(e) {
        // $(this.el)... works as supposed but what about $(my button)?
    }

}
```

Comment: As an additional info, you can use $el instead of $(this.el). It is a cached version of the jQuery object.

Comment: Hi! I've missed that completely. Where can I read more about that?

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#View I *think* it's new-ish.

Comment: Guess so, but `view.$el` is only usable from outside an view, right?

Comment: In or out (this.$el works inside a bound function in the view).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
buttonHandler: function(e) {
    var element = $(e.target);
}
```

Comment: `$(e.target)`  gives the inner-most element clicked. Use `$(e.currentTarget)` to give the element to which the event was bound.

Answer (score 0):

To get the element `#button` and not an inner element, use `currentTarget` instead if `target`. (From comment above)

```
buttonHandler: function(e) {
    var element = $(e.currentTarget);
}
```